# Aligning two divs?

Tags: css, html, alignment

bit of a CSS newb here.  I'm using the fluid grid layout in Dreamweaver CS6.  I created a headercontainer div, then headerleft and headerright divs inside it.  I've added an image to headerleft and typed some text in headerright.  I want to be able to have the text remain in line with the center of the image no regardless of resizing from the fluid layout.

What's the best way to do this?  I put the two headers in a container div hoping that it will make it easy for me to align the two divs within the container, but I'm just not sure how to achieve it.  Here's the code I currently have for this section of the page:

EDIT: Code Now says (but still doesn't work):

```
.gridContainer {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 90.5666%;
    padding-left: 0.2166%;
    padding-right: 0.2166%;
}
#headercontainer {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #FFF;
    text-align: left;
}
#headerleft {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 49.7607%;
}
#headerright {
    clear: none;
    margin-left: 0.4784%;
    width: 49.7607%;        
}
```

And the html says:

```
<div class="gridContainer clearfix">
  <div id="headercontainer">
    <div id="headerright">
      <h2>Support For All Your Gadgets &amp; Tech!</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="headerleft"><h2><img src="images/logo2.png" alt="alt" longdesc="desc"></h2>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Look into floating divs with CSS. Once you understand that I think you will find your problem pretty easy to solve. I didn't provide an answer because there are already many on SO.

Answer (score 1):

remove `display:block;` from your `#headerleft` and `#headerright`

Also, you can only set `float:left;` on the headerleft id, and put the div `headerright` before the left one in your html code.

Comment: Hi pouki, thanks for the help! Unfortunately that didn't work, the headerright is now sitting below the headerleft. That code was put there by DW when setting up the inital layout divs.  I removed float:left from headerright, and put the headerright div first in the headercontainer.  Here is the css:

Comment: Bump.  Anyone got any ideas please?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
.gridContainer {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: auto;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
}
#headercontainer {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #FFF;
    text-align: left;
    position:relative;
}
#headerleft {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 50%;
}
#headerright {
    clear: none;
    margin-left: 50%;     
}


<div class="gridContainer clearfix">
  <div id="headercontainer">

    <div id="headerleft"><h2><img src="images/logo2.png" alt="alt" longdesc="desc"></h2>
    </div>
    <div id="headerright">
      <h2>Support For All Your Gadgets &amp; Tech!</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, this didn't seem to work either.  It may have something to do with the fact that nested fluid divs aren't currently supported according to my copy of dreamweaver.  I didn't realise before.  I've managed to get an effect more or less how I want it by inserting a table into the fluid grid.  Thanks again for your help. :)